# mysql single returned value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query:

```
$a=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE p2='fruit' LIMIT 1");
```

This will only ever return one result or none.

I'm trying to first count the results, then if it 1, to pass the returned id to a variable.

Question: If I do 
`$results=count(mysql_fetch_assoc($a));`
to count the number of rows returned, can I still do later

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($a)){
    $id=$row['id'];
 }
```

or will the first delete the array somehow???

Is their a better way to do all this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really not need to do anything if there is one row or null
Consider below code it will set id value if there is 1 row fetched otherwise it will be null

```
$id=''
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($a)){
    $id=$row['id'];
 }
```

No count needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
$results=count(mysql_fetch_assoc($a));
```

does not count the number of rows as `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns one row. I believe you're looking for `mysql_num_rows`:

```
$results = mysql_num_rows($a);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($a);
```

You can then do an IF statement on this and later do a while loop on the fetched array

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `mysql_num_rows` ??

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot as each call to `mysql_fetch_assoc()` loads a new row, if there is any. You could indeed assign both variables at once:

`$results=count($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($a));`

but

But `mysql_fetch_assoc($a))` returns `false` and as the result of `count(false)` is `1` this will not tell you anything. Besides, if there is no row all you really need is `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($a)` and test `if ($row) {...}`.

Comment: No, `count($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($a))` doesn't do what you think it does, because `$row` is not an array of rows, but just a row.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when using:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($a)){
    $id=$row['id'];
}
```

it is just like reading a file,every time mysql_fetch_array($a) is called the next line is parsed untill it reaches the end of the file. A cursor of some sort is known in the background. Meaning that if you would enter by hand
    //backgroundCursor = 0
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($a)
    //backgroundCursor = 1
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($a)
    //backgroundCursor =2
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($a)
    //backgroundCursor = 3

The while instruction just automates the stuff. 
mysql_fetch_array increases the background cursor at every call so if you call it twice it will not give you the same line.

To get a clear view on this read something about reading from a file line by line.